# Dijkstra's Algorithm from Adjacency Matrix

Tags: python, graph, matrix, dijkstra

I have an adjacency matrix of a directed acyclic graph represented by a 2D array:

```
[[0, 4, 3, 0]
 [0, 0, 0, 1]
 [0, 3, 0, 1]
 [2, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Is there a Python module or a quick code snippet that can run Dijkstra's Algorithm on this data type? The Python cookbook uses a priority dictionary I believe, but I'd really like to keep it in a 2D array. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Would [Dijkstar](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Dijkstar) suit your needs?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[networkx](https://networkx.org/) might fit your needs:

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[0, 4, 3, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 1],
              [0, 3, 0, 1],
              [2, 0, 0, 0]])
G = nx.from_numpy_matrix(A, create_using=nx.DiGraph())
print(nx.dijkstra_path(G, 0, 1))
```

See also: [networkx.dijkstra_path](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.weighted.dijkstra_path.html)